# How to read csv file contains pixels value of images with Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the csv file looks like this:

```
im1000100101     0
im1011100101     1
```

The first column is pixels value of images and second column is the class of that image. How can I use `pd.read_csv()` to save the each pixel in a separate column. I want to my DataFrame looks like this:

```
px-1  px-2  px-3  px-4  px-5 px-6  px-7  px-8  px-9  px-10  label
1     0     0     0     1    0     0     1     0     1      0 
1     0     1     1     1    0     0     1     0     1      1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""im1000100101     0
im1011100101     1"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
N = 12
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(temp), header=None, widths=[1] * N + [6], usecols=range(2,13))
df.columns = ['px-{}'.format(x+1) for x in df.columns[:-1]] + ['label']
print (df)
   px-1  px-2  px-3  px-4  px-5  px-6  px-7  px-8  px-9  px-10  label
0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0      1      0
1     1     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     0      1      1
```

Comment: I had a question in your code ` + [6]` is the number of spaces?

Comment: Yes, it is number of spaces + len of data - 5 space + 1

Comment: Interesting! I edit the question, if in our csv file, in the beginning of each row if we have some string can we skip that part?

Comment: Try parameter skiprows - check [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html)

Comment: @jezreal `skiprows ` is going to skip a row, I used the `usecols` and it works. Again, thanks for the help.